# Cannot active login button when automation IOS devices on BrowserStack using Selenium

Tags: ios, selenium, browserstack

I used selenium Webdriver to automate on IOS devices on Browser Stack. But when I tried to log in by inputting username and password into login pop-up, the login button does not activate.

I had workaround on the issue and tried some others ways to input user and password text fields like using javascript or Robot framework but the issue still happened. The event that enables the login button is not being triggered.

[demo video](https://www.browserstack.com/s3-upload/bs-video-logs-euw/s3-eu-west-1/19be73bcb75941b8095effd3a0eecee125f55539/video-19be73bcb75941b8095effd3a0eecee125f55539.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIN2TCEEW2SVRV5JA&Expires=1524602462&Signature=tLTx4WIqB508MTP%2FqIcuI6SXxag%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment&response-content-type=video%2Fmp4)

The issue does not happen when automation on Android devices.

Could anyone see the same my problem or find out any idea?

Sample url: [Click Here](https://mandarinpalace-kore7.aristx.net/)

Video after clicking on Practice radio button: [Video](https://www.browserstack.com/s3-upload/bs-video-logs-euw/s3-eu-west-1/03f31c34f1fe07bf4d2728a32115e1b1a492cda4/video-03f31c34f1fe07bf4d2728a32115e1b1a492cda4.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIN2TCEEW2SVRV5JA&Expires=1524790835&Signature=gNtIbikuKN%2BwmaS2pE%2FFiwpmgrg%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment&response-content-type=video%2Fmp4)

Comment: Have you tried registering a click event on the 'Real' or 'Practice' radio button to check if an off-click activates the login button? could you update your question with a sample URL?

Comment: How many characters does your password has?

Comment: Password what you are entering is not matching the password criteria i feel, please check it once.

Comment: @Pradeephebbar: The password has 4 characters only, I'm sure the password is correct.

Comment: I can enable the login button by using javascript. But when clicking the login button, message invalid username/password is displayed although the username/password are correct. It seem the problem is the browser does not recognize text fields are inputted value.